# Postgres client errors: Database error: insufficient data in "D" message, lost synchronization with server

Tags: postgresql, client

I have a Postgresql sever which happens to be running on a NAS, on a Docker instance. It has worked flawlessly for years, but all of the sudden one of my client machines is having all sorts of strange errors when I query it.

I know that:

- The errors occur with multiple databases on the host, so not db specific.
- The errors *don't* occur with other client machines, just my main
  workstation
- A brand new Docker Postgres instance on the NAS continues to have problems, so it's not something with that docker instance
- This one client gets errors when accessing the server from multiple applications (PGAdmin4, QGIS, etc.)

I get different errors including:

- Database error: insufficient data in "D" message
- lost synchronization with server
- ERROR: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac

The only thing I've found talks about network issues, packet sniffing, etc., and it seems like it must be something else..

Is there a way to flush/reset/destroy the cache(?) of postgresql info on the client machine? Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your messages indicate data corruption over the network. Likely you have a bad NIC or bad NIC driver in your main workstation. Try replacing the Ethernet cable, upgrading the driver, and if that doesn't do it, replace the NIC.

(Could also be bad RAM, esp. if your workstation doesn't use ECC memory, but that usually manifests in other ways.)